# How Can I Delete Orphaned Pivot Cache In Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I ran the method "ListAllPivotCaches" found at:

https://contextures.com/xlpivot11.html

and got the following results which shows there are 3 orphaned pivot caches:

[image]

You can see that cache indexes 4, 5, and 6 are orphaned with no associated pivot tables. Even more troubling is cache index 4 for tblA has 1,540 which helps slow down the workbook.

How can I get rid of these orphaned pivot caches using either the Excel GUI or VBA?

Comment: By default thsi should not happen. When the Pivot Table is deleted, the Pivot Cache is also deleted. Try an alternate method. Loop though all pivot cache and refresh it `PC.Refresh`. See if that solves the issue.